# Redirecting URL form

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm starting to study web development and as exercise I was trying to make a form for redirecting in HTML with javascript and PHP.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="url"><br>
    <input class="btn" type="button" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#send").click(function(){
var url = $("#url").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "engine.php",
data: "url=" + url,
dataType: "html"
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $url        =   $_POST['url'];
        header("Location: /".$url.");

    session_destroy();
    exit;
?>
```

The main problem is that seems that the js isn't read. Futhermore I don't know if the PHP is correct. What's wrong?

Comment: what the value of $url ?

Comment: Where is that javascript? Also, it seems that you've got a typo `$_POST['ur']`

Comment: the header does not need `/` just make it 
`header("Location: /".$url.")`

Comment: You'd probably need to encode that url, also can't redirect a page through ajax (if that was your intention)

Comment: I want pass in my idea (with ajax) the url written in the input field. But if there is an faster way I'll use that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to make an AJAX request if you want to redirect to another URL. Also, the way your doing it at the moment wouldn't redirect anyway.

Below, when your click function fires, it will get the URL from your input field, and re-direct to that page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#form_name").submit(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            var url = $("#url").val();

            document.location.href = url;

        });

    })

</script>
<form id="form_name" name="form_name">
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url"><br>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if I presse enter I have as result '?url=WhatIwrote' instead if I press the button I have '/undefined'

Comment: maybe you edit your code , but in this answer you don't have any tag with `id="url"` and $("#url").val(); should not work for you

Comment: Updated with the `id="url"` param

Comment: Now is almost perfect ;) when I click the button works OK, instead when I press enter I have ?url= instead of /

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery `.submit()` function? That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add id to input

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url"><br>
```

and also header() don't work in ajax

you need to use javascript for redirect

in php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $url        =   $_POST['url'];
    echo '<script>document.location.href = '.$url.'</script>';

    session_destroy();
    exit;
?>
```

and put echo text into document with ajax respond function

also you can use a better way ( with out Ajax and submit form )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#send").click(function(){
var url = $("#url").val();
window.location.href = url;
});
```

here is the best answer for you [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

**UPDATE:**
also you need delete , tags, here the html code instead of ...

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url"><br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" id="send" value="Send" />
```

Comment: with the second code you wrote nothing happen if I clickthe button instead if I press enter I have ?url= and I don't want that

Comment: what is the value of url ?

Comment: @AlessioMTX you need to delete <from> tag , i update the answer

Comment: @AlessioMTX when you have <form> tag without setting method . after you click on submit button you will be redirect to ?url=.. , you need to delete the from tag , or use .submit() function.

Answer (score 0):

So you think your javascript isn't being executed?  Does that mean you've debugged this?

If none of your javascript runs - including your ready handler, then the server isn't finding the js files.  If some of your javascript is running it's possible that an error is causing it to stop. You probably just need to do a little debugging.